# Why is UIButton instantiation causing my app to crash?

Tags: objective-c, ios

My app delegate looks like

```
   [self.splashScreen viewWillDisappear:NO];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

    educationButton=[[UIEducationButtonController alloc] init];
    [window addSubview: educationButton.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And, my UIEducationButtonController looks like:

```
@implementation UIEducationButtonController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *educationButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];    
}

@end
```

And that causes my app to freeze in iPhone 4.3 simulator. Any ideas why?

(This might seem like a very specific, nonsensical question but I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my implementation theory.)

Comment: can you show the msg printed in the console at the time of the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIButton doesn't have an init method defined - use:

```
UIButton *educationButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:...]
```

class method to instantiate the button instead.

Comment: It even breaks with:
UIButton *educationButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 300.0f, 320.0f, 98.0f)];
which is a legit init method, right? initWithFrame is inherited from UIView.

Comment: @gamozii: What you are saying is wrong. Base class for all classes is NSObject

Comment: Actually both methods probably won't cause a crash (the init method is probably legit as well inherited from NSObject).  What is the actual symptom of your crash - what message are you seeing?  Are you sure that its not just showing up a blank screen because you've not actually configured your button with anything that would be visible?